# Set background in UIViewController inside navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to set my background color fullscreen (includes navigation bar and status bar also) with gradient color. Right now, I made this by creating gradient

```
func setDefaultColorBackground() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(hexString: "804b8a").cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(hexString: "42074b").cgColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

So I added layer in my `view` in `ViewController`. It works but it does't covered up the status bar and navigation bar. See this image:
[image: background]

I think the background only fill the view under navigation bar. Anyway, I am using `.xib` and load it up manually in my view controller class.

Is there any ideas how to do it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess to change the color of the navigation bar you have to write the code for it also something like this :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

or whatever color you want to provide :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

I hope it was helpful to you. Happy Coding :)